# Execute external program from Linux/Delphi 10.2 console application

Tags: linux, delphi

How can I execute an external program from a Linux console application created in Delphi 10.2 Tokyo?

What I want to do is execute a shell command with parameters like

```
/home/test/qrencode -o /tmp/abc.png '08154711'
```

I do not need the output of the program but it should be executed synchronously.

It is easy in Windows environments but as 64 bit Linux support in Delphi (after  Kylix) is quite new, I could not find any hints on the Web by now.

Any tip helping me to solve that is very appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `popen` is a commonly used approach

Comment: Thanks a lot! Searching for popen and delphi lead me to a lot of examples like http://chapmanworld.com/2017/04/06/calling-linux-commands-from-delphi/...

Comment: This is more about Linux than Delphi. For such questions search for Linux and C or C++ topics. Translation is easy enough. You'll really benefit from being proficient in reading C, because you won't find many Delphi specific examples for Linux platform topics.

Comment: Thanks, next time I will start there! Is it ok if I answer my question as soon I have a working solution?

Comment: Of course, that's fine

Comment: @David, what's not so "Delphi" on this question? If you offer some Linux compiler that you can use for some of Unix systems to build a command line application, isn't your responsibility to offer such basic thing like executing a command if you cannot do many others from code?

Comment: @Victoria It's a platform service. Agnostic of language. In just the same way that CreateProcess on Windows is not a native Delphi function.

Comment: @David, sorry, but who cares? EMBT claims support for it. Btw. there's e.g. `TFile` class. Extending it e.g. to a sort of `Execute` static method might not take much time to implement for all platforms.

Comment: @Victoria There's no such thing in Windows either. Just the Windows API.  CreateProcess. A cross platform process launcher is surprisingly hard to construct because the platform capabilities are grossly different.

Comment: @David, I'm not working with platforms different from Windows, but I'm really suspicious on what you say. Is it really that difficult to execute a command with parameters on all Delphi supported platforms? Maybe, before you answer try to check FreePascal (sorry, have just tablet, it would take ages :)

Comment: @Victoria So long as your needs are very simple then it's not difficult to abstract commonality. It's not long before you hit problems though. Consider forking vs inheriting handles. These are hardly obscure topics. In Windows world inheriting handles is important when using piped standard handles. How does that map onto Linux? And again I stress that the situation on Linux regarding RTL is the same as on Windows. Platform API is fully available.

Comment: @Victoria and imagine if you ask the same question in the context of Windows. What is the answer? It is CreateProcess, which is a Windows function, and not a Delphi function.

Comment: @David, stop right there, please :) OP needs to just execute a command line from a console app. compiled by Delphi compiler for 64-bit Linux target, nothing more (as far as I got it). And as for me, I see no problem when EMBT would add a (a)synchronously executed procedure like `TFile.Execute` (what's the problem to implemet such for all supported platforms?) for all cross platform file execution handling. What you can do on Linux platform these days with Delphi, btw.? If one of "major" points is handling the command line, then executing a command is the most important thing ;)

Comment: @Victoria Sure they could add that. And then the next person would ask for a bit more functionality, because the asker of this question is not the only user. And that would likely be a good thing. You'd end up with something like the Qt process class. It would still be limited, but so long as your needs were basic enough then that would be fine. But it doesn't exist at the moment. Not on Windows. Not on Linux. So this is a platform specific question.

Comment: @David, of course! But try to think like that, if there's not a specific program already written for what you ask, there can be one that you can run from the Linux shell. And that seems to be the question (well, I would preferably access things like "command line" rather than claiming that I'm supporting a certain platform).

Comment: @Victoria I'm being pragmatic and realistic. You can be purist and idealistic, but if you want a solution what do you do? Wait for somebody to create a cross platform Delphi wrapper to abstract away platform process creation differences? Or do it now using the platform API. For problems like this it pays to be able to read C and be able to find resources targeting C, that being the native platform language. Then map them to Delphi.

Comment: @David, seeing the OP's question today, isn't just executing a command line tool that is able to create a QR code all that you can do for this task now (without translating C like code to Delphi)? And what seems to be asked here is a synchronous execution of a program with specified parameters on Linux platform, nothing more?

Comment: @Victoria I don't really understand that comment. Never mind.

Comment: @David, so I don't mind :) I was referring to the question that was asked (maybe) today and sounded like _"How to dynamically create a bitmap from a QR code (on Linux platform)?"_ If you're able to provide an example of a command line execution with parameters, I think it's fine for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Davids hint pointed me to an example that helped creating the solution. The most tricky part was finding out how to convert a Delphi string to a MarshaledAString as the example used a const string as argument for popen. I tested on RHEL 7.3, runs like a charm.

```
uses
  ...
  System.SysUtils,
  Posix.Base,
  Posix.Fcntl,
  ...;

type
  TStreamHandle = pointer;

function popen(const command: MarshaledAString; const _type: MarshaledAString): TStreamHandle; cdecl;
      external libc name _PU + 'popen';
function pclose(filehandle: TStreamHandle): int32; cdecl; external libc name _PU + 'pclose';
function fgets(buffer: pointer; size: int32; Stream: TStreamHandle): pointer; cdecl; external libc name _PU + 'fgets';

function runCommand(const acommand: MarshaledAString): String;
// run a linux shell command and return output
// Adapted from http://chapmanworld.com/2017/04/06/calling-linux-commands-from-delphi/
var
  handle: TStreamHandle;
  data: array [0 .. 511] of uint8;

  function bufferToString(buffer: pointer; maxSize: uint32): string;
  var
    cursor: ^uint8;
    endOfBuffer: nativeuint;
  begin
    if not assigned(buffer) then
      exit;
    cursor := buffer;
    endOfBuffer := nativeuint(cursor) + maxSize;
    while (nativeuint(cursor) < endOfBuffer) and (cursor^ <> 0) do
    begin
      result := result + chr(cursor^);
      cursor := pointer(succ(nativeuint(cursor)));
    end;
  end;

begin
  result := '';
  handle := popen(acommand, 'r');
  try
    while fgets(@data[0], sizeof(data), handle) <> nil do
    begin
      result := result + bufferToString(@data[0], sizeof(data));
    end;
  finally
    pclose(handle);
  end;
end;

function createQRCode(id, fn: string): string;
// Create qr-code using qrencode package
begin
  deletefile(fn);
  if fileExists(fn) then
    raise Exception.create('Old file not deleted!');
  // I am targeting rhel for now, so I know the path for sure
  result := runCommand(MarshaledAString(UTF8STring('/usr/bin/qrencode -o ' + fn + ' ''' + id + '''')));
  if not fileExists(fn) then
    raise Exception.create('New file not created!');
end;

function testqr: String;
// Test QR Code creation with error handling
// QREncode does not output anything but who knows ;-)
begin
  try
    result := createQRCode('08154711', '/tmp/myqrcode.png');
  except
    on e: Exception do
    begin
      result := 'Error: ' + e.message;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Regarding the discussion underneath my question I would like to say that IMHO this is about Linux AND EQUALLY anoput Delphi as knowledge of the linux API calls alone would not have helped me finding this solution.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this code to do this task

```
uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Classes,
  Posix.Base,
  Posix.Fcntl;

type
  TStreamHandle = pointer;

  TLinuxUtils = class
  public
    class function RunCommandLine(ACommand : string) : TStringList;overload;
    class function RunCommandLine(Acommand : string; Return : TProc<String>) : boolean; overload;
    class function findParameter(AParameter : string) : boolean;
  end;



  function popen(const command: MarshaledAString; const _type: MarshaledAString): TStreamHandle; cdecl; external libc name _PU + 'popen';
  function pclose(filehandle: TStreamHandle): int32; cdecl; external libc name _PU + 'pclose';
  function fgets(buffer: pointer; size: int32; Stream: TStreamHAndle): pointer; cdecl; external libc name _PU + 'fgets';


implementation

class function TLinuxUtils.RunCommandLine(ACommand : string) : TStringList;
var
  Handle: TStreamHandle;
  Data: array[0..511] of uint8;
  M : TMarshaller;

begin
  Result := TStringList.Create;
  try
    Handle := popen(M.AsAnsi(PWideChar(ACommand)).ToPointer,'r');
    try
      while fgets(@data[0],Sizeof(Data),Handle)<>nil do begin
        Result.Add(Copy(UTF8ToString(@Data[0]),1,UTF8ToString(@Data[0]).Length -1));//,sizeof(Data)));
      end;
    finally
      pclose(Handle);
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Result.Add(E.ClassName + ': ' + E.Message);
  end;
end;

class function TLinuxUtils.RunCommandLine(Acommand : string; Return : TProc<string>) : boolean;
var
  Handle: TStreamHandle;
  Data: array[0..511] of uint8;
  M : TMarshaller;

begin
  Result := false;
  try
    Handle := popen(M.AsAnsi(PWideChar(ACommand)).ToPointer,'r');
    try
      while fgets(@data[0],Sizeof(Data),Handle)<>nil do begin
        Return(Copy(UTF8ToString(@Data[0]),1,UTF8ToString(@Data[0]).Length -1));//,sizeof(Data)));
      end;
    finally
      pclose(Handle);
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Return(E.ClassName + ': ' + E.Message);
  end;
end;

class function TLinuxUtils.findParameter(AParameter : string) : boolean;
var
  I : Integer;
begin
  Result := false;
  for I := 0 to Pred(ParamCount) do
  begin
    Result := AParameter.ToUpper = ParamStr(i).ToUpper;
    if Result then
      Break;
  end;
end;
```

You do not have to worry about MarshaledString.
The RunCommandLine function has 2 ways to be called. The first you have the return on a TStringList with all the lines that the console will return.
The second you can pass an anonymous method that will treat line by line of return of the command line.

Comment: I relied on http://chapmanworld.com/2017/04/06/calling-linux-commands-from-delphi/