# Delphi 10.3.3 How to view pdf file on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, delphi, firemonkey

My app downloads the file from the server and it saves the file in the default download directory.
How can I open the file after downloading to view it.

```
try
        MS := TMemoryStream.Create;
        try
          Http.Request.BasicAuthentication:= true;
          Http.Request.Username := '*****';
          Http.Request.Password := '****';
          Http.Get('http://'+serverIP+':8080/api/getpdf/'+fType, MS);
          MS.Position:=0;
          {$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
          MS.SaveToFile(fl);
          {$ENDIF}
          {$IFDEF LINUX}
          MS.SaveToFile(fl);
          {$ENDIF}
          {$IFDEF ANDROID}
          if PermissionsService.IsPermissionGranted(JStringToString(TJManifest_permission.JavaClass.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) then
          begin
           MS.SaveToFile(fl);
          end;
         {$ENDIF}         
         previewFile(fl,fType);<--------------
        finally
         MS.Free;
        end;
      finally
        Http.Free;
      end;
```

**In windows platform I do:**

```
ShellExecute(0, 'open',PChar(fl),nil,nil,0)
```

Any suggestion for Linux?

Comment: have a look at this, especially comments to the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44415054/execute-external-program-from-linux-delphi-10-2-console-application

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to **sddk** I end up with this solution, works great under Ubuntu 19.1

```
procedure TfrmMain.previewFile(fl,fType:string);
var
 a:string;
 M : TMarshaller;
 {$IFDEF ANDROID}
  Intent      : JIntent;
  URI         : Jnet_Uri;
 {$ENDIF}
begin
 AniIndicatorItems.Enabled:=false;
 AniIndicatorItems.Visible:=false;
 rcMaskItems.Visible:=false;
 TabItem1.Repaint;
 {$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
  ShellExecute(0, 'open',PChar(fl),nil,nil,0) ;
 {$ENDIF}
 {$IFDEF LINUX}
  fl:='xdg-open '+fl;//<-------------------------------------
  popen(M.AsAnsi(PWideChar(fl)).ToPointer,'r');//<-----------
 {$ENDIF}
 {$IFDEF ANDROID}
  if PermissionsService.IsPermissionGranted(JStringToString(TJManifest_permission.JavaClass.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) then
  begin
   if fType='1' then//pdf
    OpenPDF(fl)
   else//excel
    OpenXLSX(fl);
  end;
 {$ENDIF}
end;

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{$IFDEF ANDROID}
procedure OpenPDF(const AFileName: string);
var
  LIntent: JIntent;
  LAuthority: JString;
  LUri: Jnet_Uri;
begin
  LAuthority := StringToJString(JStringToString(TAndroidHelper.Context.getApplicationContext.getPackageName) + '.fileprovider');
  LUri := TJFileProvider.JavaClass.getUriForFile(TAndroidHelper.Context, LAuthority, TJFile.JavaClass.init(StringToJString(AFileName)));
  LIntent := TJIntent.JavaClass.init(TJIntent.JavaClass.ACTION_VIEW);
  LIntent.setDataAndType(LUri, StringToJString('application/pdf'));
  LIntent.setFlags(TJIntent.JavaClass.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
  TAndroidHelper.Activity.startActivity(LIntent);
end;
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
procedure OpenXLSX(const AFileName: string);
var
  LIntent: JIntent;
  LAuthority: JString;
  LUri: Jnet_Uri;
begin
  LAuthority := StringToJString(JStringToString(TAndroidHelper.Context.getApplicationContext.getPackageName) + '.fileprovider');
  LUri := TJFileProvider.JavaClass.getUriForFile(TAndroidHelper.Context, LAuthority, TJFile.JavaClass.init(StringToJString(AFileName)));
  LIntent := TJIntent.JavaClass.init(TJIntent.JavaClass.ACTION_VIEW);
  LIntent.setDataAndType(LUri, StringToJString('application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'));
  LIntent.setFlags(TJIntent.JavaClass.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
  TAndroidHelper.Activity.startActivity(LIntent);
end;
{$ENDIF}
```

For android you need this also: [DW.Androidapi.JNI.FileProvider.pas](https://github.com/DelphiWorlds/KastriFree/blob/master/API/DW.Androidapi.JNI.FileProvider.pas)

Comment: Were you asking about opening the .PDF in an app running on Ubuntu or Android?  The title of your q specifically says "on Ubuntu" and the body of the q asks "Any suggestion for Linux?", not Android.

Comment: First: I add the extra code for android to other users who may come across this thread and may get help. Second: I meant Ubuntu = Linux.